# How to check if a String value already exists in a Array list?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parameters

I have two classes in BlueJ, SuperHero and SuperWeapon. I need to create a method that adds super weapons in the Arraylist. The method is supposed to be called with a parameter of the type SuperWeapon.

This means that the method assumes that a SuperWeapon object exists. The method is therefor not supposed instantiate a new SuperWeaponobject.

And only weapons with unique names may be added to the list, therefor a control of the new SuperWeaponobject is needed.

The code below is what i currently have, from what I understand, the code right now does not check if a superweapons name is unique when made. Sorry if the code is a little bit weird, i translated it to english from swedish but I hope someone understands what I am in need of.

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SuperHero
{
    private ArrayList<SuperWeapon> superWeaponList;
    private String superHeroName;
    public SuperHero()
    {
        superHeroName = "Superman";
        superWeaponList = new ArrayList<SuperWeapon>();
    }
    public void addSuperWeapon(SuperWeapon superWeapon)
    {
        if(superWeaponList.contains(superWeapon))
        {
            System.out.println("The Superhero already has a superweapon with the name: " + superWeapon.getName() + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            superWeaponList.add(superWeapon);
            System.out.println("A new superweapon has been registred for the superhero");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a List of Strings as your title suggests. You have to implement ``equals`` in your ``SuperWeapon`` class in order to make ``contains`` work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to solve your problem either change to a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<SuperWeapons>>` which maps the superhero's name to his weapons or else override the equals method in the superhero's class such that two superhero's are equal if their names are the same rather than the same object i.e., memory location